# compare subsequent lines in a file using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a following below entry in the file

```
UK99_08
UK99_08
UK99_08
UK99_08
UK99_08
UK99_17
UK99_17
UK99_17
UK99_17
UK99_17
UK99_19
UK99_19
UK99_17
UK99_17
UK99_17
UK99_20
UK99_17
UK99_17
UK99_17
```

I need to display the first entry of the duplicate and rest of the lines that matches the first entry should have NULL, should look like this using awk

```
UK99_08



UK99_17



UK99_19

UK99_17


UK99_20
UK99_17
```

,

Comment: If Null cannot be displayed, should look like this
UK99_08
*
*
*
*
UK99_17
*
*
*
*
UK99_19
*
UK99_17
*
*
UK99_20

UK99_17
*
*

Comment: why `UK99_17` come multiple times?

Answer (score 4):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{print ($0==p?"":$0); p=$0}' file
```

Explained:

```
{
    print ( $0==p ? "" : $0 )  # if current record is the same as p print "", else $0
    p=$0                       # store current record to p 
                               # for comparing on next iteration
}
```

Comment: Could you add some lines of explanation, @James?

Comment: @VM17 Sure. It's just that I'm on a vacation in Miami and the network is s l o w . . .

Answer (score -2):

```
while read line
do
  if [ $line = $previousLine ]
  then
    echo;
  else 
    echo $line
    previousLine=$line
  fi
done < my_file
```

Comment: Wrong approach and wrong syntax. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and google why you must quote shell variables and the problems with echo.